# how to hide skitter-slider jquery plugin's Next and Prev navigation buttons

Tags: jquery, css, skitter-slider

[skitter-slider](http://www.skitter-slider.net) plugin is setup with following props but whenever I mouse over the slides the next and prev buttons become visible. 
I need to remove the buttons even when mouse is over the slides. I think it should be handled by navigation: false but it does not work.

```
<!-- Init Skitter -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.box_skitter_large').css({width: 530, height: 110}).skitter({
                theme: 'round',
                numbers_align: 'center',
                navigation: false,
                enable_navigation_keys: false,
                progressbar: false, 
                dots: true, 
                preview: false,
                hideTools: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I have also tried adding display:none  to all following classes in skitter.styles.css file.

```
.skitter-round .prev_button, 
.skitter-round .next_button,
```

Comment: Could not understand your question properly. Do you want to show previous, next button of hide it? if you want to hide it than navigation: false should do the trick.

Comment: to hide you need `display:none;` right..

Comment: Also you display:block CSS is causing the issue please try by removing it or make it display:none;

Comment: @Nimmi: I want to hide the prev and next buttons. i do not know why this does not work. maybe i should try a clean one.

Comment: @karanthakkar  : i corrected my mistake in question. after navigation:false does not work i add display:none to all navs but does not work

Comment: Is it to any specific browser?

Comment: I used chrome and IE. and both shows the button even if i change the theme only the ui and placement of buttons changes.

Comment: Or else try by giving display: none !important;

Comment: dear nimmi it is resolved by adding important. please post your answer so i can mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **skitter.styles.css** and change this line `display: block;` to

```
 display: none !important;
```

In **skitter.styles.css**,

```
    /* =Round theme
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */
.skitter-round .prev_button, 
.skitter-round .next_button, 
.skitter-round .play_pause_button, 
.skitter-round .focus_button 
{
    display: none !important; // change to this
    background: url('../images/sprite-round.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it is handled and overridden by skitter itself when mouse is over

Comment: @imanabidi I have checked this one using "display: none !important;" and its working :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use display: none !important; to resolve this issue.

Comment: sorry that i should choose newTag answer because it is more complete and will helps new comers better. but i really appreciate your help